# Flutter: Make A Video A Circular Button

Tags: flutter, button, video, shapes

I have a local .mp4 that is playing with video_player. I am trying to crop it or overlay it so it is looks like a circle of the center part of the video then make that a button. I have tried variations of Stack, Containers w/ BoxDecoration:borderRadius, buttons, ClipRRect to round corners and overlay to no avail. If you run the code you will see the video. I would like the crop/overlay to be just inside the edge boundary of the Sun.

```
video_player: ^2.4.2

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:video_player/video_player.dart';

class HeaderSun extends StatefulWidget {
  const HeaderSun({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  State<HeaderSun> createState() => _HeaderSunState();
}

class _HeaderSunState extends State<HeaderSun> {
  late VideoPlayerController _controller;
  late VideoPlayer sdo;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _controller = VideoPlayerController.network('https://sdo.gsfc.nasa.gov/assets/img/latest/mpeg/latest_1024_0193.mp4');
    _controller.setLooping(true);
    _controller.setVolume(0.0);
    _controller.initialize().then((_) {
      _controller.play();
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    sdo = VideoPlayer(_controller);
    return Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).scaffoldBackgroundColor,
        appBar: AppBar(
          toolbarHeight: 120,
          backgroundColor: Colors.black,
          actions: [
            Expanded(
              child: 
              Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                children: [
                  Container(
                    height: 120,
                    width: 120,
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      // shape: BoxShape.circle,
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50),
                    ),
                    child: ClipRRect(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50.0),
                      clipBehavior: Clip.hardEdge,
                      child: IconButton(
                        iconSize: 120,
                        onPressed: () async {
                          await showDialog(
                            context: context,
                            builder: (_) {
                              return Dialog(
                                backgroundColor: Colors.black,
                                shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                                ),
                                child: SizedBox(
                                    height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                                    width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                                    child: sdo
                                    ),
                              );
                            } //SDOVideo()
                          );
                        },
                          icon: sdo
                      )//),
                    )
                  )
                ],
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
      body: const Text('SDO 193'),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`ClipRRect`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ClipRRect-class.html) widget :

```dart
ClipRRect(
  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(60.0),
  child: VideoPlayer(),
  clipBehavior: Clip.hardEdge, // It's highly advisable to use this behavior to improve performance.
);
```

Comment: Thanks @triple7 unfortunately this still did not crop the video as much as I would like. I added a code snip.

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, you are wrapping the `sdo` widget in a `SizedBox`, not a `ClipRRect`. The video is loaded in a dialog, which is completely separate from the widget tree where the `ClipRRect` is.

Comment: Nope it didn't work